# Automatically Launch App during iPhone Call

Tags: iphone

I suspect the answer to this is 'no' (as with so many iPhone questions), but I wanted to be 100% certain :)

Is there any way I can launch a phone call within an iPhone app and then have my app immediately re-launch (during the call) so that I can display some information about the call in progress?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. The answer is no, at least for apps developed with the SDK. Jailbreak is a whole other story. :)