# Can I launch my application from a call event?

Tags: iphone

How can I launch my application when the user make a call from the iPhone?
Does the application needs to run as a service all the time for this or can I run it from the call even though it closed?

Comment: No, not possible. Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344738/automatically-launch-app-during-iphone-call

Answer (score 3):

Launching an app in reaction to a call is not possible in iOS.